# apt-get install error while processing vsftpd: cannot create directory

Tags: apt-get, vsftpd

I receive the following error when using RVM to install ruby with `rvm install 2.3.0`. This is from the log file RVM produces.

```
Setting up vsftpd (3.0.3-8+b1) ...
vsftpd user (ftp) already exists, doing nothing.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/srv/ftp’: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package vsftpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vsftpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Infact, anytime I run an apt-get install command I always get this warning about vsftpd. I have always just ignored it as packages install just fine. The main problem now is that RVM is now picking up on this error as being critical so it stops installing Ruby.

The problem is that the folder `/srv/ftp` physically can not be created even by root (or at least I don't know how to). The way my server is set up is that the `/srv/` folder only exists to mount external disk drives so I can't create an arbitrary folder here.
E.g. `datadisk01` would be mounted onto `/srv/datadisk01`

Is there a way to change where vsftpd creates this ftp folder to a different location so it will run properly? OR is there a way I can force RVM to ignore this error message?
I would prefer the answer that fixes the error but my main objective is just to get Ruby installed.

I have already tried removing vsftpd with apt-get but it still persists.

Comment: Try [`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq vsftpd`](https://askubuntu.com/a/619956). Note that this is a problem with your operating system's package manager and is unrelated to RVM, Ruby, or programming as defined within the help center. This question is better suited to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) or [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

Comment: ah brilliant, Ruby installs fine now :) ah, sorry for posting it on the wrong site and irrelavant topics. I'll try to be more concise in the future. Thanks!